# i want to use if -else statemnt in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    user_groups.*, 
    groups.grp_display_name,
    CASE user_groups.uug_active 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'YES'
        WHEN '0' THEN 'NO'
    END AS usr_active
FROM
    user_groups,
    groups
WHERE
    user_groups.uug_is_deleted = 0
        AND user_groups.group_id = groups.id
```

This is my case statement for sql.......but the problem is i can't use alias name in my search query.

For example: this is my search query

```
ug.uug_active  LIKE "+ Query.escapeVal('%'+Query.escape(body.search.value)+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the alias in the where clause, only in group by or having clauses. You have 2 options:

1. Repeat the complete case structure in the where clause and filter on the expression: `...where case ... end like ...`
2. Filter in the having clause or move your query without filtering into a subquery, and filter in the outer query.

Although, in this particular example I would transate the search expression into 1 or 0 on application level and search for 0 or 1, instead of the string.

Comment: sorry sir,i don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: when i am using case statement in where clause it shows error

Comment: And do you expect me to use my mind reader skills to find out what error message you received or are you going to share what you have tried and what error message you received?

Comment: SELECT 
    user_groups . *, groups.grp_display_name,

FROM
    user_groups,
    groups
WHERE
(CASE user_groups.uug_active 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'YES'
        WHEN '0' THEN 'NO'
    END) 
and
    user_groups.uug_is_deleted = 0
        AND user_groups.group_id = groups.id

Comment: And the error message you received was? My guess is that you are not doing anything with the case structure in the where, you do not compare it with anything.

Comment: Again, if I were you, I would map the yes-no on application level to 1-0 and search for that rather than using a case in the where clause.